# How to use .net_reactor?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, reactor

Anyone has used .net_reactor before to protect the code?
I have protected the executable assemblies but somehow without the license file,i am still manage to run the executable

[image]

[image]

Tried sample project,output as follows:

[image]

[image]

I have also created a sample project using the SDK to get the values of the different parameters values as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using License;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            string HardwareID;
            string HardwareIDLicense;
            InitializeComponent();
            HardwareID=License.Status.GetHardwareID(true, true, true, false);

            HardwareIDLicense = License.Status.License_HardwareID;
            MessageBox.Show("HardwareID" + HardwareID);
            MessageBox.Show("HardwaeIDLicense" + HardwareIDLicense);
        }
    }
}
```

I got the following output for HardwareIDLicense:

[image]

It is empty:
Anyone knows why?
what do i need to set?

License file has also been generated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have used .net reactor before and It makes sense that your code is still runnable.

Depending on what your trying to accomplish your code will be runnable. The main reason to use .net reactor is to **obfuscate** your code. Obfuscation will not prevent your code from being ran it just makes your code harder to decompile.

If you are trying to lock your assembly, make sure to follow .net reactor's documentation for this process. Just running .net reactor will not lock the assembly. See - http://www.eziriz.com/help/source/quick_lock.html

Comment: I have done according to the above,but i can still run without the license file

Comment: Under step 7 Configure Lock Settings, did you make sure to set flag Run Without License File equal to false? By default it looks to be set to true.

Comment: Also, this may be obvious, but verify you are copying the protected dll to your build folder. If you accidentally place the unprotected dll then it won't work.

Comment: I have protected the executable file.Attached pictures are my settings.Look at my edited question.Any of my setting is wrong?If i successfully protected the executable file,what would i see when i tried open the executable file?

Comment: Look at my previous comment and compare that to your screen shot. You have Run Without License File set to TRUE. Set this to false, run protect, copy the file and try again.

Comment: i have set it to false still the same trying it on sample windows form project also the same,have edited my question on the setting i did to build my project please check

Answer (score 0):

If you use the .NET Reactor Visual Studio Add-in to automatically protect your software you should check "Project Output Is Part Of A Deployment Project". This way the compiled file will be directly replaced with the protected one. Otherwise the proteced file will be copied in into "..._secure" sub directory.
If you directly run the protected application from the _secure sub directory it should show you the hardware ID.

The SDK library License.dll is only a dummy assembly which doesn't contain real licensing and hardware ID code. The only purpose of License.dll is to make references in your compiled software. Then at protection time .NET Reactor replaces the references and injects the real code. That's the reason why it works only correctly after protection. Therefore it is very important that you actually executes the protected file.